# React useEffect updating with default initialized useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to create an array state variable called `usersInfos` that I can append to whenever I do an api call, but useEffect is updating with the initial value of the `userData` state variable.

```
// api.js
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchUserData () {
    return axios.get('https://randomuser.me/api')
    .then(res => {
        return res;
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
}
```

```
import { fetchUserData } from '../../src/api';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ProfileCard from './profilecard';

export default function UserProfile() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
    const [usersInfos, setUsersInfos] = useState([]);

    const getUserData = async () => {
        let ud = await fetchUserData()
        setUserData(ud);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserData();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        const newInfos =  [
            ...usersInfos,
            userData,
        ]
        setUsersInfos(newInfos);
        console.log(usersInfos);
    }, [userData])

    return (
        <div className='userprofile'>
            <button onClick={() => { getUserData() }}> Fetch Random User </button>

            <button onClick={() => { console.log(usersInfos) }}> log usersInfos </button>

            {usersInfos.map((user, idx) => {
                <ProfileCard userData={user} key={idx} />
            })}
        </div>
    )

}
```

I'm assuming it's something to do with the state batch updating, but I'm not sure. What would be the best practice way of doing this?
I am console logging with the button at the bottom, after the page has loaded.

When `userData` is initialized to `()`, I get console log: `(2) [undefined, {…}]`

When `userData` is initialized to `(0)`, I get console log: `(2) [0, {…}]`.

When `userData` is initialized to `([])`, i get console log:`(2) [Array(0), {…}]`

Thanks

Comment: Setting state is (generally) [a batched/async process](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) as you pointed out so you can't immediately log the results of changing it. If you want to log it use another `useEffect` to check for changes in the state: `useEffect(() => console.log(usersInfos), [usersInfos]);`

Comment: I'm logging it after with the button at the bottom, Why does the useEffect append the initialized state though if it should only happen when the state changes?

Comment: Think of `useEffect(..., [foo])` as "the effect runs for every value of foo". It runs for the initial value, and it runs when the value changes.

Comment: @yousoumar `userData` is normally an array, I changed the initialized state to test if that is what its appending.
@Martin yes, because it only runs when the value changes, I am confused why it appends the initial state and not the new one.

Comment: @Sujio thanks for the answer. Did you try the response given below by Micro Bellagamba?

Comment: @yousoumar Hello again, Yes I did and it works, but once again I would like to know why its happening this way. I updated my question with more examples

Comment: @Sujio 1. You must initialize the `userData` with an empty array.  2. You must also spread the `userData`  in the `useEffect`: `const newInfos =  [...usersInfos, ...userData]`

Comment: @Fraction I just tried spreading `userData` both with an initialized empty array and with no initialization, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: userData is not iterable` both times

Comment: have you checked if `fetchUserData` always returns an array ? otherwise you have to add a check in your first `useEffect`

Comment: yes `fetchUserData` always returns an array. It is just an axios call to `randomuserdata.me`. I'll add the code to the original question, cause someone else asked the same thing

Comment: in `fetchUserData` you have to return `res.results`

Comment: I am getting the expected data. Only the `useEffect` is appending the initial state instead of the updated state, if you look at the examples at the bottom of my question, the `{...}` is the correct data

Comment: you must apply all the fixes mentioned above and also I checked the api and it returns the result under `res.data.results`, this is [a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-sky-ijy937?file=/src/MyComponent.js)

Comment: Thanks, if you want to write up an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: Sorry you were right. I was following a tutorial blindly. I re-checked the api and the object I was looking at looked like an arrray but was not.

Answer (score 2):

When the 2nd effect runs for the first time, `userData` is undefined because the network request isn't resolved yet. You could simply run the effect only when userData is not undefined.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (userData) {
    const newInfos =  [
      ...usersInfos,
      userData,
    ]
    setUsersInfos(newInfos);
  }
}, [userData])
```

However, if the code presented in the question is almost complete, I would use the code below instead. In this way I can update both states with a single effect.

The code below is a snippet from the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-hooks-yjnb3k?file=/src/App.js) fully functional example.

```js
export default function UserProfile() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();
  const [usersInfos, setUsersInfos] = useState([]);

  const getUserData = useCallback(async () => {
    let ud = await fetchUserData();
    setUserData(ud);
    setUsersInfos((prevInfos) => [...prevInfos, ud]);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
  }, [getUserData]);


  return (
    <div className="userprofile">
      <button onClick={getUserData}>Fetch Random User</button>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(usersInfos);
        }}
      >
        log usersInfos
      </button>
      {userData && (
        <p>
          Current user: {userData.name.first} {userData.name.last}
        </p>
      )}
      <ul>
        {usersInfos.map((user, idx) => (
          <ProfileCard userData={user} key={idx} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you try to log userInfos just after the setter, it will log the previous state because the function inside the effect is a closure and it captures the value of the state when the effect runs. Since React state is immutable the state update does not works like an assignment but it will be updated at the next render.

Comment: Remove `usersInfos` from the array dependency or it causes an infinite call.

Comment: Thanks I tried this and it works. Have my upvote. Would this be considered best practice? and I updated my question with another example, the undefined is from the initialized state.  I'm wondering why it works this way.

Comment: I'm assuming leaving state uninitialized and undefined is not good practice, because further down I want to map the `usersInfos` and it breaks when `userData` is initialized as undefined.

Comment: Yes the code in my question is mostly complete, at least in this component. There is a button at the bottom that console logs after the page is loaded and is how I know the `useEffect` is updating with initial state, not undefined because of an unresolved network request. I plan to pass the data in `userData` and the list of fetched users from `usersInfos` to other components, and is why I have two states.

Comment: Anyway you couldn't need 2 effects. You could update both `userData` and `usersInfos` after the promise resolved, avoiding unnecessary re-renders.

Comment: One is for when the component loads and the other is for when the state changes... I looked around and this is how everyone does it. If you can show me a way to do both with one useEffect I would appreciate it.

Comment: I've updated the 2nd example to set both states. I've also updated the set function to avoid using previous state, which is an anti-pattern because it breaks [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) (the `usersInfos` variable is not listed in effect hook dependencies).

Comment: How would you fetch another user, keep track of the current one, and add them in order you got them to the state array then? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: I've edited the answer including a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-hooks-yjnb3k?file=/src/App.js). I hope this answer your question.

Comment: @Sujio Does it finally solve your question?